# How can I load a local thumbnail in Android WebView using the poster attribute in an HTML5 video tag?

Tags: cordova, html5-video, video-thumbnails

I'm currently using Phonegap + VideoPlayer plugin to play videos in an application that I built. I can get the click to correctly trigger the video intent such that the native application launches, but when I use a local file image to render the `poster` for the thumbnail, it doesn't work even though the file exists. Linking to a remote file does, however.

```
<video controls data-url="file:///android_asset/www/resources/videos/1.mp4" 
    poster="file:///android_asset/www/resources/images/1.jpg">
  <source src="file:///android_asset/www/resources/videos/1.mp4"></source>
</video>
```

Any ideas on how to get it working for a local `poster`?